# Java why do i keep getting collection unmodifiable exception?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to create a datatable with the in cell editor. I have a column called "groups" which shows a list of groups. When the cell editor icon is clicked, it shows a checkboxMenu where a user can check whatever groups they want and then click submit.

I don't even have my rowEditEvent handler yet and i'm getting a collection unmodifable exception. I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong that i'm getting this exception.

Any help is appreciated.

group_admin.xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable value="#{userBacking.users}" var="users" editable="true">

        <p:column headerText="Groups">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{users.groups}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{users.groups}" label="Groups">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{groupBacking.groupsAsSelectItems}" />
                    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Actions">
            <p:rowEditor />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

getUsers

```
public List<UserBean> getUsers() throws Exception {

        ContentManager cm = null;
        cm = getContentManager();

        if(users == null) {

            users = new ArrayList<UserBean>();

            UserManager um = cm.getUserManager();
            List<? extends Group> cmsGroups = um.getCmsDefinedGroups();
            List<? extends User> allUsers = um.getAllUsers(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

            // loop through each user
            for(User u : allUsers) {

                Set<? extends Group> groups = u.getGroups();

                UserBean user = new UserBean();
                user.setUserName(u.getUserName());
                user.setGroups(groups);  // THIS LINE CAUSES THE EXCEPTION
                users.add(user);
            }

        }

        return users;
    }
```

UserBean

```
public class UserBean implements User {

        private String userName;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private Set<? extends Group> groups = null;

        public UserBean() {}

        public UserBean(String userName, String firstName, String lastName, Set<? extends Group> groups) {
            this.userName = userName;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.groups = groups;
        }
        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }
        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }
        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
        public Set<? extends Group> getGroups() {
            return groups;
        }
        public void setGroups(Set<? extends Group> groups) {
            this.groups = groups;
        }
        public void removeGroups() {
            groups = null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDisabled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public UserProfile getProfile() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace

```
Oct 9, 2012 1:09:08 PM com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer createCollection
SEVERE: Unable to create new Collection instance for type java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.createCollection(MenuRenderer.java:907)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel(MenuRenderer.java:367)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValue(MenuRenderer.java:129)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:315)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectcheckboxmenu.SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(SelectCheckboxMenuRenderer.java:34)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1028)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:958)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1209)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1086)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.iterate(UIData.java:1501)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.processValidators(UIData.java:1026)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:485)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:1233)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1518)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:335)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1518)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView.visitTree(TabView.java:400)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1518)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1518)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:366)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:246)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1163)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thre
```

ad.java:662)

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @Rohit - he's highlighted the line

Comment: @BrianAgnew.. Ah sorry.. I didn't see that.. Stupid me..

Comment: It's not *obvious*, admittedly

Comment: Are you using Hibernate/JPA with lazily fetched n-m relationship sets or so? That would be my first shoot in the dark. A stracktrace would indeed give way much more insight into the concrete problem. In the future questions about exceptions, never omit the stacktrace. It's basically the whole answer at its own, one has just to translate it into layman's terms for you. This problem has at least nothing to do with JSF.

Comment: You have to Post you UserManager class. Especially um.getAllUsers() is important. Here you should return a new List instead of the field.

Comment: I've posted the stacktrace. Yes JPA is being used, but I didn't write that part and i'm not familiar with JPA.

Comment: Wow, the stacktrace is completely different from what you were implying. Why exactly did you point the particular line in your code as the line causing the exception? The exception isn't been thrown at that line at all.

Comment: The reason that I thought it was because of that line is because when i removed that line it didn't throw a stacktrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stacktrace suggests that `u.getGroups()` returned a `Collections#unmodifiableSet()`. When JSF needs to process the submitted values from the checkbox group, it is trying to instantiate a collection of the same type, but that type is uninstantiable.

Wrapping it in a modifiable set such as `HashSet` should fix the particular problem:

```
user.setGroups(new HashSet<Group>(groups));
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, there are more other potential problems in the code posted so far, but they are not related to particular exception which you faced. So, fixing the  current problem may cause a different exception, but this would not be related to the current one at all.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the other problems you're referring to?